# How to do orientations in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have a Setting page which contains setting functions of the application,there is a button called lock-rotation button,by default my application supports all the orientations,but my need is i want to set lock the rotation in my lock-rotation button,if the user tap the lock-rotation button it popups two button lock horizontally and lock vertically,if the user tap any one of this button it automatically stops the rotation of the corresponding orientation .How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but i dont think so that we can lock the orientations in iphone on Button Tap...Have you seen any App which does this orientation controlling... if yes plz do tell to me... Thanks

you try these methods for controlling the orientations...

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
}
```